# Custom highlight for field value when editing

Tags: ios

I need to do custom field data highlight for edit mode: when user tap on that field we set overlay with alpha 0.5 on whole screen but show value of field above that overlay. So it looks like we do accent on text value of field and put into background all other things on screen.

Currently I have only one idea how to do this easy:

1. Get absolute coordinates of that field (in fact it is a custom control inside table cell).
2. Add new overlay view with alpha 0.5 to current view controller's view. This put everything on screen into background.
3. Create new shape layer with bounds same as field from step 1 and add this layer as a mask to overlay view. This will do a "window" in overlay and our field will be not affected by alpha value.

The only problem with this solution is that inside "window" we have not only text but other things from field like background.

So maybe there is another solution for such overlay to have only text value above overlay?

Update.

I came up to following solution: show image of field (snapshot) in image view inside overlay view. It is easy to implement, and doing snapshot of such small area will not affect performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

subclass your uitextfield and subscribe on this notifications:

```
UITextFieldTextDidBeginEditingNotification
UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification
UITextFieldTextDidEndEditingNotification
```

then add overlap uiview as your uiwindow subview

```
UIView* myView = /* Your custom view */;
UIWindow* currentWindow = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
[currentWindow addSubview:myView];
```

override `drawRectFunc` for this custom view, where `maskRect` - frame of your textfield (must be converted to uiwindow coordinates)

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
// Drawing code
CGRect rBounds = self.bounds;

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

// Fill background with 80% white
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [[[UIColor whiteColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.8] CGColor]);
CGContextFillRect(context, rBounds);

// make the window transparent
CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeClear);
CGContextFillRect(context, self.maskRect);
}
```

hope this helps

Comment: I decided to implement this highlight with field snapshot but for original question your implementation is good.